# Can you have an ArrayList that contains Singly Linked Lists?

Tags: java, arraylist, singly-linked-list

Im trying to create an ArrayList that contains a Singly Linked List in each index.
The outputList I'm trying to create is going to hold singly linked lists which contain Strings that are sorted (right now the sorting doesn't matter if I cant get variables into the Singly Linked lists and the SLL into the ArrayList). Im curious if singly linked lists can be added into ArrayLists.

```
SinglyLinkedList sList = new SinglyLinkedList();
ArrayList<String> outputList = new ArrayList<String>();
            int size = inputList.size();
            for(int i = 0;i < (size-1);i++) {
                if(i==0) {
                    outputList.add(sList.addNode(inputList.get(i)));
                }
            }
```

inputList is an ArrayList that holds Strings.

SinglyLinkedList is defined by the code below.

```
public class SinglyLinkedList {

//From: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-program-to-create-and-display-a-singly-linked-list
class Node{
    String data;
    Node next;
    
    public Node(String data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

public Node head = null;
public Node tail = null;

public void addNode(String data) {
    
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    
    if(head == null) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else {
        tail.next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
}

public void display() {
    Node current = head;
    
    if(head == null) {
        System.out.println("List is Empty/Null");
        return;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Nodes of this singly linked list are: ");
    while(current != null) {
        System.out.print(current.data + " ");
        current = current.next;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

As suggested by an answer I used;

```
List<List<String>> outputList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> singleList = (List<String>) new SinglyLinkedList();
```

However the second line gives a runtime error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class SinglyLinkedList cannot be cast to class java.util.List (SinglyLinkedList is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at SinglyLinkedList.main(SinglyLinkedList.java:89)
```

Comment: Brief comment from mobile, not full answer: Anything that's not a primitive type (e.g. boolean, char, int) can be stored in an array list of the appropriate type. Here the correct type of the array list would probably be `ArrayList<SinglylinkedList>` or similar.

Comment: You can add any object type to an ArrayList, when you properly work with them. Having an ArrayList declared as `ArrayList<String>` and then attempt to add `SinglyLinkedList` instances there makes no sense, especially when you do so by using `sList.addNode(inputList.get(i))` which doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` can contain any object which includes `SinglyLinkedList`. For example if you want to have `ArrayList` with 3 elements:

```
List<SinglyLinkedList> outputList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   outputList.add(new SinglyLinkedList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a List can hold any Class type.  However, specifying the implementation class on the left hand side is generally frowned upon as it forces an implementation type when all you usually need is the interface.  If you're implementing the singly-linked list yourself I highly suggest you do so to the List interface.  Then you would do something like:

```
List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<>()
List<String> singleList = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
singleList.add("new data");
myList.add(singleList);
```

Now if you want to later change your secondary list, you only need to change a single line of code instead of altering every reference.

Edit: Your single linked list class should look like this:

```
public class SingleLinkedList<T> implements List<T> {

    class Node {
        T data;
        Node next;
    
        public Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

//implement all of the List interface methods
}
```

If you do that your class will now adhere to List standards.

Comment: There is an error with the List<String> line when i implement this. 'class SinglyLinkedList cannot be cast to class java.util.List (SinglyLinkedList is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')' No idea why, but it might have something to do with the <> after 'new SinglyLinkedList'

Comment: You mention "do so to the list interface." Do you have any links that would help me in this regard?

Comment: Updated to give a little clarification.